# Handy Haskell IDE

Tags: ide, software-development, haskell

Is there a good Haskell IDE? Desired features:

- Refactorings (rename, extract function, etc.)
- REPL with on-the-fly integration with the developed project.
- Somehow helps to understand cryptic GHC compilation errors
- A bit more clever auto-complete than all identifiers from the current .hs file or history.

As far as I'm aware there are *no* IDEs for Haskell meeting all this requirements (I'd be happy to be wrong), so if anything close is available for any operating system, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

A few things come to mind:

- Sublime Text with Haskell plugins
- [SublimeHaskell](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell): On Linux, I had difficulty making it work because of its dependencies, mainly because of ghc-mod, IIRC. It also made Sublime quite sluggish to respond, so it is disabled currently.
- VIM with plugins
- [haskell-vim-now](https://github.com/begriffs/haskell-vim-now) -- I've tried this, and it sets up a very nice Vim environment with many Haskell goodies. One thing I liked the best about it is being able to tell me types in nested where clauses and inside sub-expressions. But using Vim is frustrating for me, so I haven't used it more than a few hours.
- [haskellmode-vim](https://github.com/lukerandall/haskellmode-vim) -- this I haven't tried.
- [Leksah](http://leksah.org/) -- I personally haven't used it, but they self-proclaim as a Haskell IDE. IIRC I've downloaded it once a few years ago when I was starting out with Haskell, but at that time the interface seemed daunting and confusing. Lately I wanted to give it another go, but I couldn't really make it work on my Linux machine.
- More: https://wiki.haskell.org/IDEs -- Haven't read it yet, just stumbled into it searching around.

I am not fully satisfied with any of these, and it would be so nice to have something 'perfect'. If anyone has something that they feel is 'perfect' for their workflow, please share it here!

**Edit 2015-10-08:**

Inspired by this question I started snooping around again, and I've found that there is a Haskell plugin available for IntelliJ IDEA:

- https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2014-October/116567.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5PAuXiVGws

I'm in the process of setting it up and trying it out, and I am already excited because it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

For Haskell there is also a number of packages available for [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor.

- [`language-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/language-haskell): syntax highlight, must have.
- [`ide-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell): meta-package for other haskell packages, support for compilation, erros, types information and other.
- [`autocomplete-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-haskell): autocomplete for modules, symbols, classes, types etc.
- [`haskell-ghc-mod`](https://atom.io/packages/haskell-ghc-mod): support for `ghc-mod`.
- [`ide-haskell-cabal`](https://atom.io/packages/ide-haskell-cabal): support for compilation, `ide-haskell` should also be installed for proper support.
- [`haskell-pointfree`](https://atom.io/packages/haskell-pointfree): convertion pointfree/pointful notations, not requiered, but very useful.

---

I'm currently using this assembly to work on few Haskell pet-projects and found it pretty useful (previosly, I've used `SublimeHaskell` and they're quite similar in functionality).

Personally, I've found it useful for Haskell programming and still lightweight.

Comparing to the other IDEs, like Visual Studio, IntelliJ IDEA or KDevelop, it lacks some features like refactoring (code extract-inline, smart rename, move-copy and other), package management; but this bundle still does a good job with type support, autocompletion and project support.